# How do you force to_yaml to output long strings in literal block style?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have long string values in a hash that I would like to be printed in literal block style (the block beginning with `>` or `|`) in YAML, rather than as in-line strings. Is there a way to force this when calling `#to_yaml`?

Example of literal block style:

```
---
this: |
  Foo
  Bar
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dump strings in YAML using literal scalar style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640277/how-to-dump-strings-in-yaml-using-literal-scalar-style)

Answer (score 0):

This should make the trick:

```rb
require 'yaml'
require 'psych'

long_string = "Foo\nBar"
yaml_output = Psych.dump({ "this" => long_string }, { style: :literal })

# Replacing `|-` with `|`
yaml_output.gsub!("|-", "|")

puts yaml_output
```

Output:

```
---
this: |
  Foo
  Bar
```