# kubectl reformats "script" block after edit is applied

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

```
- name: getversion
      workingDir: $(resources.inputs.app.path)
      image: gittools/gitversion:5.6.10-alpine.3.12-x64-3.1
      script: |
        #!/usr/bin/env ash
        git tag
        # so we are making a hack, that if we try to merge hotfix branch into main we should 
        [ -e GitVersion-hotfix.yml ] && /tools/dotnet-gitversion | grep hotfix 1>/dev/null && (echo "hotfix"; rm -rf GitVersion.yml; cp GitVersion-hotfix.yml GitVersion.yml)

        # since this is a busybox we can't use bash regexp here
        if echo $(params.branch) | grep -E '^refs/heads/(main|release/[0-9.]+)$' > /dev/null;
        then
          local_tags=$(git tag --points-at HEAD)
          echo "remove local head tags"
          echo $local_tags
          git tag -d $local_tags
        fi
        
        /tools/dotnet-gitversion /updateprojectfiles
        git status
        chown -R "$(params.user_id):$(params.group_id)" "$(workspaces.source.path)"
        chown -R "$(params.user_id):$(params.group_id)" "$(resources.inputs.app.path)"
        echo "DONE"
```

so when I use `kubectl edit` commend, and then try to do one more time to edit it - I get this

```
 script: "#!/usr/bin/env ash\n# so we are making a hack, that if we try to merge
      hotfix branch into main we should \n[ -e GitVersion-hotfix.yml ] && /tools/dotnet-gitversion
      | grep hotfix 1>/dev/null && (echo \"hotfix\"; rm -rf GitVersion.yml; cp GitVersion-hotfix.yml
      GitVersion.yml)\n\n# since this is a busybox we can't use bash regexp here\nif
      echo $(params.branch) | grep -E '^refs/heads/(main|release/[0-9.]+)$' > /dev/null;\nthen\n
      \ local_tags=$(git tag --points-at HEAD)\n  echo \"remove local head tags\"\n
      \ echo $local_tags\n  git tag -d $local_tags\nfi\n\nsleep 3000\n\n/tools/dotnet-gitversion
      /updateprojectfiles\ngit status\nchown -R \"$(params.user_id):$(params.group_id)\"
      \"$(workspaces.source.path)\"\nchown -R \"$(params.user_id):$(params.group_id)\"
      \"$(resources.inputs.app.path)\"\necho \"DONE\"\n"
    workingDir: $(resources.inputs.app.path)
```

## How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Both ways of formatting the `script:` element are valid YAML, and they represent exactly the same multi-line string.  In other words, there's no concurrent modification being done: K8s ingests a multi-line string (started by `script: |`) and outputs a multi-line string encoded as a double-quoted single-line string with newline characters (`script: "...\n..."`)

I could find no way of customizing `kubectl`'s YAML output, so you must resort to an external formatting program to prettify the YAML file to be edited.This is one such [online formatter](https://onlineyamltools.com/prettify-yaml): (Refer to screenshot)[image] command-line formatters can be easily built e.g. with [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418449/pretty-output-with-pyyaml).

Building upon the solution presented in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418449/pretty-output-with-pyyaml), perhaps the simplest solution is to create a wrapper shell script for the editor that reformats the file to be edited then proceeds to edit it.  For example:

```
#! /bin/sh

/usr/bin/python3 -c '
import yaml, sys; 
r = open(sys.argv[1])
data=yaml.safe_load(r.read()); 
r.close();
w = open(sys.argv[1], "w");
yaml.dump(data, stream=w, default_flow_style=False, default_style="|")
w.close()
' "$1"

exec /path/to/my/editor "$@"
```