# Python YAML dump special character and multiple lines

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a `my_yaml.yml` file with the following content:

```
my_yaml:
  person: >
    John|Doe|48,
    Jack|Black|39
  skills:
    - name: superhero
      abilities:
        - swim
        - run
  special_chars:
    - '! | " "'
    - '+ | " "'
    - '\ | " "'
    - 'Á | "A"'
    - 'É | "E"'
    - 'Ű | "U"'
    - 'Û | "U"'
```

I want to load it then dump into a `my_yaml_new.yml` file having totally the same format & characters as the original input file has. My code is:

```
import yaml
my_yaml = yaml.load(open('my_yaml.yml', encoding='utf8'))  # without "utf8" encoding I get "'charmap' codec can't decode byte..." error
```

I can `dump` it into console but **1)** order of `abilities` & `name` has changed :(

```
yaml.dump(my_yaml, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

Result is:

```
'my_yaml:\n  person: >\n    John|Doe|48, Jack|Black|39\n  skills:\n  - abilities:\n    - swim\n    - run\n    name: superhero\n  special_chars:\n  - \'! | " "\'\n  - + | " "\n  - \\ | " "\n  - Á | "A"\n  - É | "E"\n  - Ű | "U"\n  - Û | "U"\n'
```

And when I try to dump into a file:

```
with open('my_yaml_new.yml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(my_yaml, outfile, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

**2)** I get the following error due to character `Û`:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xdb' in
>   position 0: character maps to undefined

If I delete this line from the input `my_yaml.yml` file then above dump is successful, but **3)** my multiple lines at `person` string go into one line :(

```
my_yaml:
  person: >
    John|Doe|48, Jack|Black|39
  skills:
  - abilities:
    - swim
    - run
    name: superhero
  special_chars:
  - '! | " "'
  - + | " "
  - \ | " "
  - Á | "A"
  - É | "E"
  - Ű | "U"
```

**4)** And also my single quotes (') are disappeared from `special_chars` :(

**5)** And also note that elements of `skills` has no indentation :(

I've tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640959/how-can-i-control-what-scalar-form-pyyaml-uses-for-my-data) solutions with no success. And nor `import ruamel.yaml as yaml` has helped.

---

**UPDATE**

OK, the following great package solves problems **1)** & **4)**, and I can replace `>` to `|` at multi line values so **3)** is also solved. And maybe **5)** is not a huge problem. But I still struggle with special characters like `Û` or `Ǘ` so I'm still looking for solution for problem **2)**...

```
from ruamel import yaml

    my_yaml = yaml.round_trip_load(open('dmy_yaml.yml', encoding='utf8'), preserve_quotes=True)
    with open('my_yaml_new.yml', 'w') as outfile:
        yaml.round_trip_dump(my_yaml, outfile, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you encounter problems with unicode. If you have your `my_yaml.yml` and a program `try.py`:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

with open('my_yaml.yml') as fp:
    yaml_str = fp.read().replace(': >\n', ': |\n')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
new_file = 'my_yaml_new.yml'
with open(new_file, 'w') as ofp:
    yaml.dump(data, ofp)
```

then that produces:

```
my_yaml:
  person: |
    John|Doe|48,
    Jack|Black|39
  skills:
    - name: superhero
      abilities:
        - swim
        - run
  special_chars:
    - '! | " "'
    - '+ | " "'
    - '\ | " "'
    - 'Á | "A"'
    - 'É | "E"'
    - 'Ű | "U"'
    - 'Û | "U"'
```

in a virtualenv for both Python2 and Python3 with ruamel.yaml 0.15.40.

I used:

```
for n in 2 3 ; do  mktmpenv -p /opt/python/$n/bin/python -qq -i ruamel.yaml; python --version; python try.py; deactivate; done
```

which of course relies on (the latest) versions of Python 2 and 3 to be installed under `/opt/python/2` resp. `/opt/python/3` (which they are on my Linux development system).

Note that the Unicode shows no problems, that the `yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)` preserves your source indentation, but that you still need to change the folded multi-line scalar to literal style (which I do while reading into `yaml_str`) as ruamel.yaml doesn't support preserving that (primarily because there is no easy way to indicate the original folding points in a transparent way).

Comment: Thanks, this solution works perfectly!!! I don't know why but I always have to force `encoding='utf-8` when I read a file let it be a `pandas.read_csv()` or a simple `with open()`. (`sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns with `utf-8`...)

Comment: That might have to do with how your Python is compiled, but I am not sure.