# How to use ruamel.yaml to output line-delimited/formatted json block?

Tags: python, json, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm currently using this code block with pyyaml, but I want to get the same thing done with ruamel.yaml

```
import yaml
import json
envList=envList={"env":"development", "region":"us", "tag":"latest", "kubesvcname":"service", "containername":"testcontainer", "namespace":"kubens", "buildid":"1000"}
jsonFile = json.dumps(envList, indent=4)
configMapHeader={ \
    "apiVersion": "v1", \
    "kind":"ConfigMap", \
    "metadata": { \
        "name": f'{envList["kubesvcname"]}_{envList["containername"]}-{envList["tag"]}-{envList["buildid"]}', \
        "namespace": f'{envList["namespace"]}'\
    },
    "data":{"appsettings.json": \
             jsonFile }
}

def str_presenter(dumper, data):
    """configures yaml for dumping multiline strings
    Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640959/how-can-i-control-what-scalar-form-pyyaml-uses-for-my-data"""
    if len(data.splitlines()) > 1:  # check for multiline string
        return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='|')
    return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data)


yaml.representer.SafeRepresenter.add_representer(str, str_presenter) 
print(yaml.safe_dump(configMapHeader, sort_keys=False, line_break=True))
```

the output of this looks something like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: service_testcontainer-latest-1000
  namespace: kubens
data:
  appsettings.json: |-
    {
        "env": "development",
        "region": "us",
        "tag": "latest",
        "kubesvcname": "service",
        "containername": "testcontainer",
        "namespace": "kubens",
        "buildid": "1000"
    }
```

When I try to do something similar with ruamel.yaml, I get the \n line breaks in the output file.

This is the code:

```
def initYamlParser():
    import ruamel.yaml as yaml
    yaml = yaml.YAML()
    yaml.preserve_quotes = True
    yaml.explicit_start = True
    return yaml

import sys
import json
yaml=initYamlParser()
envList=envList={"env":"development", "region":"us", "tag":"latest", "kubesvcname":"service", "containerver": "latest", "containername":"testcontainer", "namespace":"kubens", "buildid":"1000"}
jsonFile = json.dumps(envList, indent=4)
configMapHeader={ \
    "apiVersion": "v1", \
    "kind":"ConfigMap", \
    "metadata": { \
        "name": f'{envList["kubesvcname"]}_{envList["containername"]}-{envList["containerver"]}-{envList["buildid"]}', \
        "namespace": f'{envList["namespace"]}'\
    },
    "data":{"appsettings.json": \
            jsonFile }
}
print(configMapHeader)
with open("file.yaml", 'w+') as file:
    yaml.dump(configMapHeader, file)
```

This is the output:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: service_testcontainer-latest-1000
  namespace: kubens
data:
  appsettings.json: "{\n    \"env\": \"development\",\n    \"region\": \"us\",\n \
    \   \"tag\": \"latest\",\n    \"kubesvcname\": \"service\",\n    \"containerver\"\
    : \"latest\",\n    \"containername\": \"testcontainer\",\n    \"namespace\": \"\
    kubens\",\n    \"buildid\": \"1000\"\n}"
```

Ruamel.yaml doesn't support str_presenter, so I'm hoping either for an ruamel.yaml compatible version of that function or a way to present it internally with ruamel.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should not normally append to a file when dumping a YAML document. Since
`ruamel.yaml` write UTF-8 to files open them as `"wb"`.

You set `yaml.preserve_quotes = True`, but that only  works when you round-trip (load YAML, then dump it).

Then in `ruamel.yaml` you can have a different representer as well, just attach it to the `representer` attribute (which is an instance of the
`Representer` attribute, which defaults to `RoundTripRepresenter`). The only difference is that it is handed in a representer as first argument:

```py
import sys
import json
import ruamel.yaml
   
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.explicit_start = True

def str_presenter(cls, data):
    if len(data.splitlines()) > 1:  # check for multiline string
        return cls.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='|')
    return cls.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data)

yaml.representer.add_representer(str, str_presenter)

envList={"env":"development", "region":"us", "tag":"latest", "kubesvcname":"service", "containerver": "latest", "containername":"testcontainer", "namespace":"kubens", "buildid":"1000"}
jsonFile = json.dumps(envList, indent=4)
configMapHeader={ \
    "apiVersion": "v1", \
    "kind":"ConfigMap", \
    "metadata": { \
        "name": f'{envList["kubesvcname"]}_{envList["containername"]}-{envList["containerver"]}-{envList["buildid"]}', \
        "namespace": f'{envList["namespace"]}'\
    },
    "data":{"appsettings.json": \
            jsonFile }
}
 

# print(data)
yaml.dump(configMapHeader, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: service_testcontainer-latest-1000
  namespace: kubens
data:
  appsettings.json: |-
    {
        "env": "development",
        "region": "us",
        "tag": "latest",
        "kubesvcname": "service",
        "containerver": "latest",
        "containername": "testcontainer",
        "namespace": "kubens",
        "buildid": "1000"
    }
```

If you would load your expected output and then dump it, you can see that `ruamel.yaml` can preserve the block style literal scalar.
By inspecting the value for the key `appsetting.json`, you'll see that this is an instance of the class `LiteralScalarString`.
That knowledge can be used to make only one scalar be dumped that way (instead of all scalars that have embedded newlines):

```py
import sys
import json
import ruamel.yaml
   
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.explicit_start = True

envList={"env":"development", "region":"us", "tag":"latest", "kubesvcname":"service", "containerver": "latest", "containername":"testcontainer", "namespace":"kubens", "buildid":"1000"}
jsonFile = json.dumps(envList, indent=4)
configMapHeader={ \
    "apiVersion": "v1", \
    "kind":"ConfigMap", \
    "metadata": { \
        "name": f'{envList["kubesvcname"]}_{envList["containername"]}-{envList["containerver"]}-{envList["buildid"]}', \
        "namespace": f'{envList["namespace"]}'\
    },
    "data":{"appsettings.json": \
            ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralScalarString(jsonFile) }
}

yaml.dump(configMapHeader, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: service_testcontainer-latest-1000
  namespace: kubens
data:
  appsettings.json: |-
    {
        "env": "development",
        "region": "us",
        "tag": "latest",
        "kubesvcname": "service",
        "containerver": "latest",
        "containername": "testcontainer",
        "namespace": "kubens",
        "buildid": "1000"
    }
```

- you might want to look at `envList=envList=....`, not sure why you assign twice to the same variable
- in case you wonder: you get a dash after the literal scalar indicator `|-` because the JSON dumper output doesn't include
  a final newline

Comment: Thank you for this answer! the envList=envList=... was a typo in the question. The sample code was not exactly the code I'm really using in the actual script. This is exactly what I need