Dump JSON as multline String in Python with PyYaml
I need to do a roundtrip with some Kubernetes Resources to alter it in some way with Python (3.11).
Now i have t following ConfigMap-Resource:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: sample-map
data:
  sample.json: |-
    [
      {
        "name": "foo",
        "description": "bar"
      }
    ]

After loading it, altering it i want to dump it back, while preserving the former form. Unfortunately, i only get the following output:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: sample-map
data:
  sample.json: "[\n {\n "name": "foo",\n"description": "bar"\n}\n]"

I tried various things, but without any luck e.g with different representer combination as seen in https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/240
Does anyone have an idea how to do it?
Thanks a lot!

see my comment for the solution.

Use yaml.add_representer to indicate the function you want to use to render strings. (The particular representer used here is taken from Issue 240 as well.)
import yaml

def str_presenter(dumper, data):
    """configures yaml for dumping multiline strings
    Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640959/how-can-i-control-what-scalar-form-pyyaml-uses-for-my-data"""
    if data.count('\n') > 0:  # check for multiline string
        return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='|')
    return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data)


data = """apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: sample-map
data:
  sample.json: |-
    [
      {
        "name": "foo",
        "description": "bar"
      }
    ]"""

d = yaml.load(data, yaml.Loader)

yaml.add_representer(str, str_presenter)

print(yaml.dump(d))

(Note, though, that this does not preserver the original order of the keys. I don't recall if that's possible, but I think it's outside the scope of this question.)
Output:
$ python3 test.py
apiVersion: v1
data:
  sample.json: |-
    [
      {
        "name": "foo",
        "description": "bar"
      }
    ]
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: sample-map


Unforntunately, this does not solve it. It even does not add the "|" after the key in the output.

I updated the original question with an update and why it is failing in my case.

What breaks? The output looks the same as far as I can tell. Anyway, I answered the question you asked. If you asked the wrong question, start a new post, rather than changing the question in a way that invalidates the answer.

While you were absolutely right, i found my problem! I had some german "umlaute" inside my multiline string like üöä (cause i'm from germany). While testing i had these word inside, but removed them for this post. But these characters were the problem! i had to add the option "allow_unicode=True" to yaml.dump() and now everything work es expected. Thanks again for your input (rubberducking ;) !
