# In Pyyaml, how to represent empty strings and lists in block style?

Tags: string, yaml, dump, pyyaml, empty-list

I have added representers for folded strings, literal strings as mentioned in [Any yaml libraries in Python that support dumping of long strings as block literals or folded blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432605/any-yaml-libraries-in-python-that-support-dumping-of-long-strings-as-block-liter). I have also added representer to print a list in block style in the dumped yaml content.

But the issue is that when the string is empty, i.e., "" or the list is empty, they appear in non-block style in the dumped YAML content.

How do force the pyyaml dumper to output "" empty strings with ">" or "|" style and empty list with flow_style=False in a block style in the generated YAML content?

Answer (score 5):

After a bit of research, I am able to dump empty strings as block literals (style in '|>') in a YAML file using Pyyaml. My work is partially based on [Any yaml libraries in Python that support dumping of long strings as block literals or folded blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432605/any-yaml-libraries-in-python-that-support-dumping-of-long-strings-as-block-liter).

```py
import yaml
from yaml.emitter import Emitter, ScalarAnalysis

class MyEmitter(Emitter):  
    def analyze_scalar(self, scalar):   
        # Empty scalar is a special case.
        # By default, pyyaml sets allow_block=False
        # I override this to set allow_block=True
        if not scalar:         
            return ScalarAnalysis(scalar=scalar, empty=True, multiline=False,
                allow_flow_plain=False, allow_block_plain=True,
                allow_single_quoted=True, allow_double_quoted=True,
                allow_block=True)   
        return super(MyEmitter, self).analyze_scalar(scalar)

# And I subclass MyDumper from MyEmitter and yaml.Dumper        
class MyDumper(yaml.Dumper, MyEmitter):
    pass
class folded_unicode(unicode): pass
class literal_unicode(unicode): pass

def folded_unicode_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='>')
def literal_unicode_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='|')

yaml.add_representer(folded_unicode, folded_unicode_representer)
yaml.add_representer(literal_unicode, literal_unicode_representer)

# I test it now
d = {'foo': {'folded': folded_unicode(''), 'literal': literal_unicode('')}}
print yaml.dump(d, Dumper=MyDumper)
```

Output:

```
foo:
  folded: >
  literal: |
```

However, I am not able to find a way to dump an empty list in block style. For this, I tried to mess with yaml/emitter.py and realized that I needed a non-empty list to dump it in block style.

Anyways, this effort did not go in vain, rather it was quite exciting :)
I hope that some one may find this useful or may have something to share.