# How to set yaml.dump options to get a scalar literal

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

`yaml.load()` from a scalar literal looks like this.

```
key: |
    line 1
    line 2
```

and will get the 
`{"key": "line1\nline2"}`

how to dump the data to a file with the same scalar literal?

Comment: ok, I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640959/how-can-i-control-what-scalar-form-pyyaml-uses-for-my-data?rq=1  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432605/any-yaml-libraries-in-python-that-support-dumping-of-long-strings-as-block-liter

Answer (score 0):

If you install [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (an enhanced version of PyYAML of which I am the author) from PyPI, you only have to specify the RoundTripParser/Dumper:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

yaml_str = """\
# this is the key info
key: |
    line 1
    line 2
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper)
```

will give you:

```
# this is the key info
key: |
  line 1
  line 2
```

`data` will be a subclass of `ordereddict`/`OrderedDict` on which the formatting information and the comments are attached, which you can use in
your program in the normal way.