# JSON to YAML: convert fields with embedded newlines "\n" to literal block "|"

Tags: json, yaml, file-conversion

How to convert JSON file, where some field values are multiline strings, with embedded newlines (as "`\n`") to YAML, where values with embedded newlines and only those values are written using literal block notation.

For example given the following JSON:

```js
{
   "01ea672a": {
        "summary": "A short one-line summary",
        "description": "first line\nsecond line",
        "content": "1st line\n2nd line\n"
   }
}
```

should generate something like the following YAML (the details may differ):

```yaml
---
01ea672a:
  summary: A short one-line summary
  description: |-
    first line
    second line
  content: |
    1st line
    2nd line
```

I would prefer solution in a scripting language, be it Python, Perl, Ruby or other, or using a command-line conversion tool like [Catmandu](http://librecat.org/Catmandu/).

The [json2yaml.com](https://www.json2yaml.com/) on-line can do this, but I'd rather not try to use it for 40 MB file.

Answer (score 4):

ruamel.yaml (disclaimer: I am the author of that library), already can
round-trip your expected output without loss of any of its information
(including key order):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """---
01ea672a:
  summary: A short one-line summary
  description: |-
    first line
    second line
  content: |
    1st line
    2nd line
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.explicit_start = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

giving:

```
---
01ea672a:
  summary: A short one-line summary
  description: |-
    first line
    second line
  content: |
    1st line
    2nd line
```

If you would add:

```py
    print(type(data['01ea672a']['description']), type(data['01ea672a']))
```

you would see that these are `LiteralStringScalar` from `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring` resp.
`CommentedMap` from `ruamel.yaml.comments`. The latter you can create on the fly
by handing the type in to the JSON loader, and *it will preserve the key order* as it behaves like an ordereddict.

The former
has to be "enforced" after loading as there is no 'parse_string' option to `json.loads`, option to do so during loading.
`ruamel.yaml` has a utility function `walk_tree` that does exactly that.

With that knowledge it is trivial make a clean transformation from JSON to YAML:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
import json

json_str = r"""
{
    "01ea672a": {
        "summary": "A short one-line summary",
        "description": "first line\nsecond line",
        "content": "1st line\n2nd line\n"
    }
}
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.explicit_start = True

data = json.loads(json_str, object_pairs_hook=ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap)
ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.walk_tree(data)  

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

again giving exactly the output that you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the low-level event API to do that. Simply parse the JSON as YAML to get an event stream (YAML being a superset of JSON allows this) and then modify the events in the following way:

- Make it a *block-style* event (JSON-style is called *flow-style* in YAML).
- If it is a scalar key, make plain-style.
- If it is a scalar value, make it literal-style if the value contains a newline, plain-style else.

Finally, emit the modified events. Here's a solution with PyYaml:

```python
import yaml, types
from yaml.events import *

events = []

class Level:
  def __init__(self, is_mapping):
    self.is_mapping = is_mapping
    self.is_value = True

levels = []

with open("in.json", 'r') as stream:
  for event in yaml.parse(stream):
    if len(levels) > 0 and levels[-1].is_mapping:
      levels[-1].is_value = not levels[-1].is_value
    if isinstance(event, yaml.CollectionStartEvent):
      levels.append(Level(isinstance(event, MappingStartEvent)))
      event.flow_style = False
    elif isinstance(event, CollectionEndEvent):
      levels.pop()
    elif isinstance(event, ScalarEvent):
      if len(levels) > 0 and levels[-1].is_value:
        event.style = '|' if "\n" in event.value else ''
      else:
        event.style = ''
      event.implicit = (True, True)
    events.append(event)

with open("out.yaml", 'w') as stream:
  yaml.emit(events, stream)
```

**Note:** PyYaml supports YAML 1.1, which in some edge cases is *not* a superset of JSON. To be sure, you may use ruamel instead which does implement YAML 1.2, but I am not familiar with its code, which is why I provide a PyYaml solution.

Comment: Would it be possible to emit events as they come, instead of storing whole file in memory (as events list)?

Comment: It turns out that it cannot handle pretty-printed multi-line JSON with lines indented with TAB ("\t") character, as it was by accident in my `in.json`... not a problem with real JSON data files, which are single-line.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was able to modify the [dnozay answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20863889/46058) to the "[Any yaml libraries in Python that support dumping of long strings as block literals or folded blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20863889/46058)" question.

It turns out to be a bit faster than [flyx answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47187585/46058), though you needs some additional tricks (borrowed with modification from [drbild/json2yaml](https://github.com/drbild/json2yaml)) to preserve the order of keys.

The major part is to use **`Representer.add_representer`**:

```py
class maybe_literal_str(str): pass
class maybe_literal_unicode(unicode): pass

def change_maybe_style(representer):
    def new_maybe_representer(dumper, data):
        scalar = representer(dumper, data)
        if isinstance(data, basestring) and "\n" in data:
            scalar.style = '|'
        else:
            scalar.style = None
        return scalar
    return new_maybe_representer

from yaml.representer import SafeRepresenter

# represent_str does handle some corner cases, so use that
# instead of calling represent_scalar directly 
represent_maybe_literal_str     = change_maybe_style(SafeRepresenter.represent_str)
represent_maybe_literal_unicode = change_maybe_style(SafeRepresenter.represent_unicode)

# I needed to use it in yaml.safe_dump() with older PyYAML,
# hence explicit Dumper=yaml=SafeDumper
yaml.add_representer(maybe_literal_str, represent_maybe_literal_str,
                     Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)
yaml.add_representer(maybe_literal_unicode, represent_maybe_literal_unicode,
                     Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)
```

For it to work I had to wrap strings with one of those two classes:

```py
def wrap_strings(arg):
    """Wrap {str,unicode} arguments in maybe_literal_{str,unicode}"""
    if isinstance(arg, str):
        return maybe_literal_str(arg)
    elif isinstance(arg, unicode):
        return maybe_literal_unicode(arg)
    else:
        return arg
```

I have used this hacky function to modify the structure

```py
def transform(obj, leaf_callback):
    try:
        # is it dict or something like it?
        enum = obj.iteritems()
    except AttributeError:
        # if not dict-like, it is list-like object
        enum = enumerate(obj)
    for k, v in enum:
        # is value 'v' collection or scalar (leaf value)?
        if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
            transform(v, leaf_callback)
        else:
            newval = leaf_callback(v)
            if newval is not None:
                obj[k] = newval
```

The conversion from JSON to YAML was done with:

```py
def convert_dom(json_file, yaml_file):
    loaded_json = json.load(json_file)
    transform(loaded_json, wrap_strings)
    yaml.safe_dump(loaded_json, yaml_file,
                   explicit_start=True, # start with "---\n"
                   default_flow_style=False)


with open('in.json', 'r') as json_file:
    with open('out.yaml', 'w') as yaml_file:
        convert_events(json_file, yaml_file)
```

Comment: You refer to preservation of the order of the keys as they are in JSON, but I can't figure out where in your code you actually do that. I would expect an an extra parameter to  `json.load()` in your final example is needed for that.

Comment: @Anthon: Ah, true, in my code I have instead `loaded_json = json.load(json_file, object_pairs_hook=MyOrderedDict)`, where `MyOrderedDict` is subclass of `collections.OrderedDict` "monkey-patched" so that `.items()` method returns list-like object with `.sort()` method that does nothing. This was needed because `json.load` sorts keys for some reason, and as far as I know you cannot turn this behavior off.

Comment: `yaml.(safe_)dump()` sorts the keys of dict before dumping the dict. I know there is code on [so] that prevents that from happening by changing the representer for dicts, but your "patch" of the `.sort()` method works as well, I had never thought about doing it that way.