# How to add literal string pattern in PyYaml with chomping indicator |-

Tags: python, pyyaml

I am trying generate a YAML file from Python object in which I have some literal string attribute `pattern = "^[0-9]+$"` to add to equally named node `pattern` as folder block.

#### Code

So far I have progressed till below code

```
import yaml
class MyDumper(yaml.Dumper):
    def increase_indent(self, flow=False, indentless=False):
        return super(MyDumper, self).increase_indent(flow, False)


source = {'row_filters':{'NONE':{'filter_sql_expr': True}},
          'rule_dimensions': ['completeness','conformance'],
          'rules': {'VALID_CUSTOMER_ID': {'rule_type': 'REGEX', 'dimension': 'accuracy', 'params': {'pattern': "^[0-9]+$"}}}}    

print(yaml.dump(source, Dumper=MyDumper, default_flow_style=False,sort_keys=False,indent=2,allow_unicode=True))
```

#### Actual YAML Output

```
row_filters:
  NONE:
    filter_sql_expr: True
rule_dimensions:
  - completeness
  - conformance
rules:
  VALID_CUSTOMER_ID:
    rule_type: REGEX
    dimension: accuracy
    params:
      pattern: ^[0-9]+$
```

#### Expected YAML output

```
row_filters:
 NONE:
   filter_sql_expr: |-
      True
rule_dimensions:
  - completeness
  - conformance
rules:
  VALID_CUSTOMER_ID:
    rule_type: REGEX
    dimension: accuracy
    params:
      pattern: |-
        ^[0-9]+$
```

#### Wanted

I need to add `|-` for multi-line block with [block chomping indicator](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#8112-block-chomping-indicator) - in order to add strings as block literals.

#### Questions

1. How to force the adding the string in block-style with `|-` ?
2. How to add the method to my my Dumper class for conversion ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Representer.add_representer()` to show block literals, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20863889/13573168)

```
class folded_str(str): pass

class literal_str(str): pass

class literal_unicode(str): pass

def change_style(style, representer):
    def new_representer(dumper, data):
        scalar = representer(dumper, data)
        scalar.style = style
        return scalar
    return new_representer

import yaml
from yaml.representer import SafeRepresenter

yaml.add_representer(literal_str, represent_literal_str)

fse = True
ptrn = "^[0-9]+$"

source = {'row_filters':{'NONE':{'filter_sql_expr': literal_str(fse)}},
          'rule_dimensions': ['completeness','conformance'],
          'rules': {'VALID_CUSTOMER_ID': {'rule_type': 'REGEX', 'dimension': 'accuracy', 'params': {'pattern':literal_str(ptrn)}}}}

print(yaml.dump(source))
```

**Output**

```
row_filters:
  NONE:
    filter_sql_expr: |-
      True
rule_dimensions:
- completeness
- conformance
rules:
  VALID_CUSTOMER_ID:
    dimension: accuracy
    params:
      pattern: |-
        ^[0-9]+$
    rule_type: REGEX
```

Comment: I have tried this but the problem is the source dictionary is getting created from file and on updating ptrn to literal_str(ptrn) the value is coming in String format "literal_str(ptrn)" due to which it causing an issue in calling the function literal_str. Is there any other approach which can be invoked from My Dumper Class

Comment: can we add this in the My Dumper Class. As although your approach is fine I am looking for an alternative solution which will fit my scenario asI have to create the Source dictionary and on creating it takes all values as Strings and literal_str will not get executed and will be treated as String

Comment: For that string, can you use `eval` method, like `eval('literal_str(ptrn)')`